# Php Mailer no envía correos al cambiar de hosting

Tags: phpmailer

Tengo el siguiente código que en otro hosting si me enviaba correos :

```
//Envio de correo electronico al usuario

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "correo.ZZ.com.ve"; //ultima modificacion hecha por juan ortiz
$mail->Port = 465;// or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "mi correo"; //ultima modificacion hecha por juan ortiz
$mail->Password = "mi contraseña ";    //ultima modificacion hecha por juan ortiz
$mail->SetFrom("juanjoseortiz@sci.zz.com.ve","Juan Ortiz"); //ultima modificacion hecha por juan ortiz
$mail->Subject = "Nuevo Ticket #".$id_ticket;
$mail->Body = "

    <div style=\"width: 800px;height: ".(350+(strlen($_POST['observacion'])/6))."px;border: 1px solid #ddd;border-radius:6px;\">

  <div style=\"width: 770px;height: 20px;margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 20px; color: inherit;color: #333;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #ddd;padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;\">

        <strong>Nuevo Ticket</strong>

         <img src=\"http://www.helpdesk.diarcasa.com.ve/images/img2.png\" style=\"width: 40px;height: 25px;float: right;\">

  </div>

  <div style=\"border-top: 1px solid #ddd;padding: 15px;background:white;\">  

      Hola <strong>".$resultado['personaNombre']." ".$resultado['apellido']."</strong>,<br> Has creado un nuevo ticket y ha sido enviado con éxito al departamento de Sistemas.

      <table style=\"border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;margin-bottom: 20px;\">
        <tr>
          <th style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">Numero de Ticket</th>
          <td style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">".$id_ticket."</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">Fecha y Hora de Envio</th>
          <td style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">El ".$fecha[2]."/".$fecha[1]."/".$fecha[0]." a las ".$ticket->hora."</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">Estado de Su Ticket</th>
          <td style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">Por revisar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">Tipo</th>
          <td style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">".$solicitud."</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">Prioridad</th>
          <td style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">".$prioridad."</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">Titulo</th>
          <td style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">".$_POST['titulo']."</td>
        </tr>

      </table>

        <fieldset>
            <legend><strong>Observación</strong></legend>
            ".$_POST['observacion']."
        </fieldset>

  </div>

</div>";
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->AddAddress($_SESSION['ticket_email']);
$mail->AddAddress("juanjoseortiz@sci.zz.com.ve");// es la direccion de correo a donde enviamos una copia de lo ocurrido
$mail->Send();
//fin del codigo
```

Cambié de hosting por cuestiones de trabajo al 
zz.com.ve donde me dicen que el host del correo es 
ese o mail.zz.com.ve .

Traté de ver cual era el puerto usado para el envio de correo de ese servidor
al entrar al correo con mi usuario y contraseña pero no aparece por ningun lado.

Mi problema es que estoy seguro que necesito ese parámetro al menos para conseguir que se envíen los correos, pero , ¿hay alguna otra cosa que este omitiendo o haciendo mal?
Gracias

En la pagina web 
https://www.zz.com.ve/es/ayuda 
aparece que el El servidor de correo es correo.ZZ.com.ve

Yo puedo acceder a mi correo sin problemas.

Answer (score 2):

En mi caso, cuando uso PHP Mailer y necesito que la conexión sea por SSL uso este fragmento:

```
    $email->SMTPOptions = array( 'ssl' => array(
                                            'verify_peer' => false,
                                            'verify_peer_name' => false,
                                            'allow_self_signed' => true  )  );
```

Espero que te pueda servir. En cualquier caso. Aumenta el nivel de SMTPDebug  y ponlo a 4 (verbose), si hay errores, debería ponerte un montón de texto en pantalla y darte una pista sobre cual es el problema que tienes.

Comment: no bro , necesito que sean con ssl ya solucione (y) la cosa era asi

Answer (score 0):

segun la pagina web en la seccion de ayudas , esto se debe agregar para que funcione el php mail

```
  $to = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@happyuser.zz.com.ve';
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

es usando el hosting de https://www.zz.com.ve/es/ayuda
ya envia correos (y)